# C++ Query builder for SPARQL queries

Tags: c++, sparql, qsqlquery

This is my first post in stack-overflow, so sorry in advance for possible "bad practices".

**Context**: the goal is to send *SPARQL* queries through http-requests to a GraphDB data base.
**Problem**: to construct the queries on code in a safe way. Currently done by means of `std::string dummyStr = "Hello"+" World"` or `dummyStr.append("bla")` (I was told this was not safe due to XSS, but thats not the issue here)

**Question:** do you know any query builder library for doing this string concatenation?
A search for *C++ query builder* on the web returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346357/c-sql-query-building-library) answer.
After implementing the approach with the suggested Qt QSqlQuery class, I'm able to ".prepare" the query, but not to ".bindValue".

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.open();
QSqlQuery startQuery;
/*Prepare query*/
startQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
          "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
startQuery.bindValue(":id", 1001);
startQuery.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
startQuery.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
/*convert query to std::string*/
QString startQueryString = startQuery.lastQuery();
std::string dummyQuery = startQueryString.toUtf8().constData();
```

Why can't I bind the values to the placeholders?
Is it because I have no "actual" database, but rather a dummy-database just to construct the query?

My actual Query looks something like this: 
`SELECT ?s WHERE { FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?s),":referenceIRI")). ?s rdf:type rdfs:Class.}`
And I would like to treat `:referenceIRI` as a placeholder.

I've searched overall to try to overcome this problem, as I just need the query-builder functionality.

**Also**: on my actual SPARQL query I have both `?` and `:myVal` elements, which are the 2 types of placeholders in QSqlQuery for binding values. Any idea on how to by-pass the `?` placeholder and just consider the `:myVal`-type?

Comment: BTW, `INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname)` is impossible in SPARQL. Perhaps the [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) keyword could help.

Comment: Thanks @stanislav, I tried that but still the same result, the values are not binded